# create dummy for group-specific maximum value occurence, conditional on overall maximum

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Let's assume I have a dataset similar to this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

state <- c(rep("Alabama", 10), rep("Arizona", 10), rep("Arkansas", 10))
county <- c(rep("Baldwin", 5), rep("Barbour", 5), rep("Apache", 5), rep("Cochise", 5), rep("Arkansas", 5), rep("Ashley", 5))
date <- rep(seq(ymd('2012-04-06'),ymd('2012-04-10'),by='days'), 6)
stray_dogs <- c(lag(1:3, n = 2, default = 0), floor(runif(7, min=1, max=4)),
                   lag(1:6, n = 5, default = 0), floor(runif(4, min=1, max=18)),
                   lag(1:2, n = 1, default = 0), floor(runif(8, min=1, max=4)))

df <- data.frame(state, county, date, stray_dogs) %>% 
  mutate(stray_dogs_max = max(stray_dogs)) %>% 
  mutate(most_stray_dogs = case_when(stray_dogs_max == stray_dogs ~ 1,
                                      stray_dogs_max != stray_dogs ~ 0))
```

I would like to find the date when the highest number of stray dogs were found in each county via `group_by(state, county)` or anything similar and create a dichotomous variable (column), which takes the value of `1` for that particular day (and takes `0` for the rest of days). However, when there were **no stray dogs at all** in a particular county during the time period, it should mark the day as `1` when `most_stray_dogs` equals to 1; and when there are multiple days with the same number of stray dogs within a county, it should pick the day which is **closer to the day of** `most_stray_dogs == 1`.

For the latter bit, my intuition would be to use a helper vector, created with `difftime`; nevertheless I just can't put together all these at once. How should I create this column?

Comment: `mutate` does the same thing in `dplyr` as `ave` does in `base`. Using both together doesn't make sense. Your code *might* work if you change `mutate(stray_dogs_max = ave(stray_dogs, FUN=max))` to `mutate(stray_dogs_max = max(stray_dogs))`.

Comment: That said, I don't understand what you mean by *"when there were no stray dogs at all in a particular county during the time period, it should mark the day as 1 when most_stray_dogs equals to 1"* - this seems circular?  I think it would clear things up if you made your example smaller - say 2 counties  and 4 dates, and showed the actual expected output. This problem doesn't seem so complicated that it needs 30 rows to demonstrate, and smaller examples are usually clearer.

Comment: it worked with `ave` inside `mutate`, but I recognize it's not standard syntax; I fixed it following your suggestion, thanks! As for the second question: I want to create a column capturing the date of the **county-specific** maximum -- and only when it's zero, it should take the value when the **national** maximum occurs.

Comment: Much clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works. No "right answer" is provided and the data is big enough to make it hard to eyeball, so I'm not positive, but it's methodical so it should at least get you on the right track.

In calculating the data difference I arbitrarily subtracted `0.1` as a tie-breaker between an equal number of days before and after the national max. I then `arrange` each group to assign the top choice (which is a bit inefficient, but should be quick enough).

```
df %>% arrange(state, county, date) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(national_count = sum(stray_dogs)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    is_national_max = national_count == max(national_count)
  ) %>%
  group_by(state, county) %>%
  mutate(
    is_county_max = stray_dogs == max(stray_dogs),
    days_from_national_max = abs(date - date[is_national_max] - 0.1)
  )  %>%
  arrange(state, county, desc(is_county_max), desc(days_from_national_max)) %>%
  mutate(your_result = as.integer(row_number() == 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(state, county, date)
```